# How to invert colors with Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I was doing some research on how to invert colors with Applescript. For the most part, I just found stuff like:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "8" using {command down, option down, control down}
end tell
```

But on Yosemite (And I think versions before this), this won't work. You have to go into system preferences and click around in there. So, is there a way to make an applescript that would invert colors?(Preferably without having to "Click" anything because that requires accessibility rights for the script)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the 'do shell script' command in Applescript, using this:
do shell script "sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleInterfaceTheme Dark"
That should turn on "dark mode" in OS X Yosemite. Cheers!

Comment: I just tried that. It gave me this error: "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Answer (score 0):

In Yosemite JXA Javascript (should be readily adaptable to AS if you prefer)
toggling dark theme and desktop color together:

```
function run() {
    var dctSettings = {
            darkMode: {
                day: true,
                night: false
            },
            background: {
                day: "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Pro Ultra Dark.png",
                night: "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Light.png"
            }
        },
        strMode;


    app = Application("System Events");

    if (app.currentDesktop.picture() === dctSettings.background.day) {
        app.currentDesktop.picture = dctSettings.background.night;
        app.appearancePreferences.darkMode = dctSettings.darkMode.night;

        strMode = "Night";

    } else {

        app.currentDesktop.picture = dctSettings.background.day;
        app.appearancePreferences.darkMode = dctSettings.darkMode.day;

        strMode = "Day";
    }
    return strMode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "System Events"

key code 28 using {command down, option down, control down}

end tell
```

It's **28** and not **8**, Key code 28 is for the "8" key on the main part of the keyboard.